# Reading XMl Data same nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have got the following XML data.

```
    <userAddress>
     <addr>
      <streetAddress/>
      <streetAddress>some street</streetAddress>
      <streetAddress>town</streetAddress>
      <streetAddress>city</streetAddress>
      <streetAddress>London</streetAddress>
      <postCode>L45 1SG</postCode>
     </addr>
    </userAddress>
```

I am trying to read each of the street address line and store the value in a variable with the following code.

```
    XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xmldata);
    var address = elem.Descendants("addr").ToList();
     foreach (var adr in address)
     {
       current_user.address_1 = addr.Element("streetAddress").Value.ToString();
       current_user.address_2 = addr.Element("streetAddress").Value.ToString();
       current_patient.address_3 = addr.Element("streetAddress").Value.ToString();
       current_patient.address_4 = addr.Element("streetAddress").Value.ToString();
       current_patient.address_5 = addr.Element("streetAddress").Value.ToString();
       current_patient.post_code = addr.Element("postCode").Value;
     }
```

The problem i am facing with the above code is that it is assigning the first line value of the streetAddress to all the variables address_1, address_2, address_3, address_4, address_5.

Comment: xml is not well formed...

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i can't change the XML.

Comment: then go with @piyush solution it will work for you

Comment: How is the code supposed to know which `streetAddress` you're referring to? You could create an array of the `streetAddress` elements and read out the values by index though this will break if a new element is added. Ideally, the elements should have `id` attributes to identify them.

Comment: @DGibbs This is exactly why i wrote assign the values "based on your criteria". If the XML can not be changed that could be index based or if know then any other manipulation. My answer was to help OP get all the values from xml with which he was struggling.

Comment: @PiyushParashar My comment was not directed at you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the list of addresses then you can get the  elements directly. Then you have to assign the values based on your criteria

```
XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xmldata);

IEnumerable<XElement> addresses = elem.Descendants("streetAddress");
```

Now you can loop through this and assign the values.